# Is there a Java or Ruby library for generating MOBI ebook documents?

Tags: java, ruby, pdf, clojure

There is a Python library for this in the Calibre project, but I would like to find a library that I can use from Clojure or Ruby. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the KindleGen tool [available from Amazon here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000234621). It's a command line tool used to build eBooks that can be sold through Amazon's Kindle platform. You can call it from Java or Ruby.