# FOSS java library to generate *.mobi ebooks?

Tags: java

Firstly there is an almost identical question but the answer is not really satisfactory.

[Is there a Java or Ruby library for generating MOBI ebook documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032131/is-there-a-java-or-ruby-library-for-generating-mobi-ebook-documents)

The answer basically gives a link to amazon and discusses using command line tools which is not really satisfactory for a web app. I want a regular jar file w/ an api that i can invoke without any nasty process invocation.

Does anyone know of a FOSS library that provides this functionality ? I would rather simething like ITEXT that allows me to build the document and then writes the mobi file rather than something that converts an already ready PDF into the MOBI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I've been able to find is a ruby library called KindleR. https://github.com/josh/kindler

I've only used it to convert basic HTML pages to mobi with pretty good success. I've never converted anything with more complicated formatting, so YMMV.